# How to prevent custom View inside CoordinatorLayout from intercepting other View's behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-coordinatorlayout, androidx

Here is a simple layout:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <View android:id="+id/view1" />

    <View 
        android:id="+id/view2"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" />

    <CustomView 
        android:id="+id/custom_view" />

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now let's suppose that `CustomView` is the largest, like its size is the same as the device's screen, while it can be transparent and should not handle any touch input events. Under this situation, I find the `layout_behavior` defined in `view2` will no longer work. So why does this happen and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance for any ideas or answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to use the behavior of the

```
app: layout_behavior = "@ string / bottom_sheet_behavior"
```

Right? As [CoordinatorLayout is a super-powered FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout) then you should put

```
<View
    android: id = "+ id / view2"
    app: layout_behavior = "@ string / bottom_sheet_behavior" />
```

below **CustomView** for the behavior to work.

Comment: I can't do that because my `CustomView` **should** be at the top layer of `View` hierarchy. I mentioned that this custom `View` is full-screen sized but transparent. It only becomes non-transparent at some certain time so it should not intercept touch events, like blocking bottom sheet behavior, during other time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I haven't understood your question correctly, but couldn't you just set *clickable* to *false*?

```
android:clickable="false"
```

As you could toggle it programmatically;

```
view.isClickable = false //true
```